# sum amount field in model using another model in django

Tags: python, django

I have three models: User, Campaign and Donation. The donation model has a donation amount, donated by each user against each campaign.

**Campaign model**

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # this is many to one relationship, on_deleting user, profile will also be deleted
    campaign_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

**Donation model**

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # this is many to one relationship, on_deleting user, user's donation details will be set to NULL
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    donation_amount = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py file**

```
def landing_page(request):
    # campaigns = Campaign.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    campaigns = Campaign.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    ////DO SOMETHING HERE TO SHOW TOTAL DONATION AGAINST EACH CAMPAIGN////

    return render(request, 'core/landing_page.html',{'campaigns':campaigns})
```

Using the current views.py file, I'm able to display all the campaigns, how do I pass the total donation against each campaign to the html file?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use annotate like this.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

campaigns = Campaign.objects.annotate(donations=Sum('donation__donation_amount'))
```

Every compaign object will have a `donations` attribute with value to sum of total donations for that compaign.

Comment: similarly say if i wanted the number of donations, can i do something like this along with your line ?

`campaign = Campaign.objects.annotate(donation_count=Count('donation__donation_amount')`

Comment: Yes. you can do `(donation_count=Count('donation'))` on the same queryset. `__donation_amount` part is not necessary for `Count`.

Comment: i did `campaigns=Campaign.objects.annotate(donations_count=Count('donation'),donations=Sum('donation__donation_amount'))` and got both donations_count and donations. Thank you

Comment: how should one do total and count for a specific campaign. say i have :

` campaign = Campaign.objects.get(campaign_link=campaign_link)`

How can i get the total donations and donations count for this particular campaign.

i tried `campaign1=campaign.objects.annotate(donations_count=Count('donation'),donation_total=Sum('donation__donation_amount'))` but that does not work

Comment: you need to annotate then use `get` like this. `Campaign.objects.annotate(...).get(campaign_link=campaign_link)`